# C/C++ mixed programming: gdb segmentation fault frequently

Tags: c++, c, crash, gdb

I always meet gdb crash when I try to print a definitely valid structure/variable. And it often crash if I tried to call another function in gdb. I found this could happen only if the code is C/C++ mixed.

For example,

```
%> p anotherFunction()
Segmentation fault
```

Here is a small example which is my typical scenario:

```
example.cc:

class foo(){
    public void bar();
};

void foo::bar(){
    int i=12345;
    printf("%d", i);
}

foo * pfoo;

extern "C" call_foo(){
     pfoo = new foo();
     pfoo->bar();
}
```

in the example, if I stop at the printf and try to execute "p i" in gdb, it will leads to crash.

Please note this is just an example, please don't look for bug in the example. Such crash happens everywhere but sometime everything is OK.

I guess this is because I debugged from C code (call_foo in this example) to C++ code and gdb has some problem to switch the context.

Please help if you have any idea. It really affects my productivity much :(....

BTW, I already tried different version of gdb. It seems the problem exists in each version include the latest one. And I have also tried purify/valgrind to verify my programs and I did't see any error with the program.

Comment: Different versions of gdb have already been tried even the latest one.

Comment: Then I think you should obtain/compile the latest GDB with debugging informations, reproduce the problem, obtain stack traces etc. (assuming your GDB can debug at least itself if not your own application) and fill a bug report towards GDB. GDB should not crash however buggy would your own application be.

Comment: Yes I think this could be the only way now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any crash in GDB is a bug in GDB. Please file the bugs in GDB [bugzilla](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/).

If multiple versions of GDB crash on your example, the problem may be with your compiler (but even then GDB should not crash).